# Conversion of data types with pandas read_excel()

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm loading some excel files with `pandas.read_excel()` and converting to a numpy array with `.to_numpy()`.
Fast forward, I solved the problem by specifying `dtype=object`. But still, I'm curious about what triggers this response.

Here is a simplified version. This is what the excel file contains:

[image]

Then I use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel('test_file2.xlsx', sheet_name='other').to_numpy()
print(data)
```

And the outcome is a string, an integer, and a float.

```
[['true']
 [0]
 [4.4]]
```

However, if both numbers in excel are floats like this:

[image]

Then this is the outcome:

```
[[True]
 [nan]
 [nan]]
```

Can anyone explain why in the second case there is such a conversion which basically leads to losing the number values?

Comment: What version of pandas and numpy are you using? I can't reproduce this with pandas 0.25.1 and numpy 1.17.2

Comment: I checked that I have older versions. Pandas is 0.24.1 and Numpy is 1.16.1.

Comment: **Update:** I updated both numpy and pandas versions and also tried across different IDE, but I still get the same result.